# git/svn repository management Web GUI

Tags: git, svn, repository

I was wondering if anyone know of good Git and SVN Management Web Based GUI with maybe the following features:

1. Create/Delete/Modify Repositories
2. User Database and User Management (Create/Delete/Modity Users)
3. Repo Permission Management (Add Read/Write Permissions for Users in certain repos)

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about to try gitlab or gitblit if you want to manage repositories on your own servers?
Both are web-based repository management tools.
Look into links below.
[GITLAB](http://gitlabhq.com/)
[Gitblit](http://gitblit.com/)

Comment: thanks man, just what i was looking for, did not find these in google though, weird :)

Comment: it's my pleasure :) i just read your question when considering to use them.

Answer (score 3):

[SCM Manager](http://www.scm-manager.org/)

- Easy
- Lightweight
- Git-SVN-Mercurial from a box
- Rich plugins set
- BSD-Licensed

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [GitHub](https://github.com/) to me?

Apparently they added [SVN support](https://github.com/blog/626-announcing-svn-support) a while back. They also do private repositories for businesses.

Comment: Hi @mikera, yeah, kinda like github, but my boss wants to host on our own servers :(

Comment: Seems like an odd requirement - why? Unless you are absolutely paranoid about security I don't see a problem with hosting on GitHub. It's cheap, it's well maintained, will be far less effort and it's probably got better security than your own servers anyway.

Comment: i don't know why, but they want something that is hosted on our own servers.

Comment: If I was in your position, I would question that decision. Have they really thought through all the pros/cons? I've found a hosted SCM solution like GitHub to be ideal for small development shops/projects.